# Custom annotation for JAX-RS method and parameter passing to JAX-RS method from interceptor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy

I will introduce a little bit wider context to clarify my use case...

I would like to implement custom annotation @FilterResponse to annotate JAX-RS method in order to filter fields in JSON response. For latter purpose, I'm using Jacksons's @JsonFilter mechanism. Idea is to enable usage of dot notation to specify wanted fields in whole object graph, starting from returned entity as a root.

For example, if I have method that returns Product entity and I want to return only name field from Product and name field from associated entity CharacteristicValues within a Product, I will do something like this...

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/{pid}")
@FilterResponse(include = {"name", "characteristicValues.name"}, responseEntityClass = Product.class)
public Response get(@PathParam("pid") Integer pid) {
    Product result = productService.findSimpleProduct(pid);
    return Response.ok().entity((result)).build();

}
```

Under the hood, in interceptor implementation for @FilterResponse annotation, I perform all necessary transformations and configuration of ObjectMapper.

Further, inside interceptor I generate some objects that can be useful in the rest of request processing (in Services, in DAOs, etc), so **I would like to pass that objects created in interceptor (for example, my FieldTree object created from metadata specified in @FilterResponse annotation) to intercepted JAX-RS method...** And that is my problem right now.

**UPDATE**: For example, passed FieldTree could be used to reconstruct JPA EntityGraph in order to fetch only preferred fields from database.

Here is pseudo-cod of interceptor to illustrate idea...

```
@FilterResponse
@Interceptor
public class FilterResponseInterceptor {


@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

    List<String> fieldsToRetain = getIncludeListFromFilterResponseAnottationIn(context);

    FeildTree fieldTree = createFieldTreeFrom(fieldsToRetain);
    passFieldTreeToMethodInContext(fieldTree, context);

    Object response = context.proceed();

    return filteredResponseWithFields(response, fieldsToRetain);
}}
```

When I try to declare paramter which I want to pass to intercepted JAX-RS method from interceptor, as shown below...

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/{pid}")
@FilterResponse(include = {"name", "characteristicValues.name"}, responseEntityClass = Product.class)
public Response get(@PathParam("pid") Integer pid, FieldTree requestedFieldTree) {
    Product result = productService.findSimpleProduct(pid);
    return Response.ok().entity((result)).build();

}
```

...I'm getting following error...

```
RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class app.fieldsfiltering.FieldTree of content type: */*
```

Is there any way to make RESTEasy to ignore some paramters in JAX-RS method, or some other way to perform parameter passing to intercepted JAX-RS method?

Sorry for my lengthily question.

**UPDATE2**: Some clarifications of my idea... I didn't mention that I would like to avoid "trivial" DTOs that are purely selection of some fields from domain entity without change of the structure. So...  EntityGraph for example will be created in DAO or Service layer... But, i feel that "metadata" necessary for EntityGraph creation (e.g. preferred field graph or FieldTree as I called it)  should be placed on JAX-RS method. Why? In that case, I would pass FieldTree to Service logic... then, I would create appropriate EntityGraph and eagerly fetch domain entity with all fields defined in FieldTree.. then, I would return domain entity to JAX-RS method and retain only fields defined in FieldTree in JSON response in order to avoid LazyInitialization exception that will be thrown if Jackson try to parse some  lazy field in entity object.

Comment: Why do you want parameter injection?

Comment: Because, I want, for example, in later stage of request processing in DAO layer, to create JPA EntityGraph from fields defined in include list of @FilterResponse annotation. In other words, I would like to filter not only JSON response but also to define what associations to be fetched from database, according to mentioned fields list.

Comment: Sorry, I meant parameter injection instead e.g. field injection so the methods do not need changes. But now I read it again, Putting this 'logic' in an interceptor feels wrong. Should that not be part of a service class?

Comment: I don't feel it is completely wrong place... Annotation + interceptor just hide JSON response filtering logic that utilize Jackson's api.. Without them, this logic will be placed in JAX-RS method... So, I don't feel it is wrong place... For me, JSON generation is complete presentation layer responsibility... To simplify, I want  in declarative way to define what fields from domain entity object  to return in json response. I will use that information also to define EntityGraph and to restrict in that way entity fetching  from db to only preferred fields .

Comment: Ok, then most likely I had an unclear picture about what your intention was (happens very often with code that is written by yourself and only described in text). But the other part remains... Why not use field injection? And 'filtering' of responses and building entity graphs for me is service logic. A jax-rs frontent should only 'convert' (but that is my point of view/approach)

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses... I tried clarified my idea again in update2 in original question